# Is it safe to climb everest base camp in the month of september?

Tags: mount-everest, solo-trekking, everest-base-camp

I am visiting Nepal for the first time this year most probably in the month of September. I am planning to trek Everest base camp starting from namacha bazaar till khumbhu icefall. Please let me know if it is safe to trek Everest base camp in September.

Comment: I can't really think of an answer to this. It is too broad in general. Secondly, what is *safe*?! Please ask more specific e.g. about typical weather and/or conditions in that region on monthly base.

Comment: By definition, just being at Everest Base Camp is more unsafe than many people would ever consider, so as Wills said, you'll need to qualify your question. Safe compared to what?